# Lexicographic product of graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am seeking to use the undocumented Mathematica function

```
GraphComputation`GraphProduct[G1,G2,type]
```

to compute the lexicographic product of graphs `G1` and `G2`. I can get this function to work for the Cartesian product but not for the Lexicographic product. Does anyone know how it works?

Comment: Can you provide a specific example you're trying to get to work?

Comment: for example let G1 = CompleteGraph[3] and G2 = CycleGraph[5], and then use GraphComputation`GraphProduct[G1,G2,"Lexicographic"].

Comment: A better question is: how to implement this type of product?  I don't see any reason to assume that the undocumented function you mention could do this.

Answer (score 11):

Playing around with Szabolcs' implementation, it appeared to me that the adjacency matrix of the lexicographic product can be easily described by `KroneckerProduct`. This led me to a second method, which seems to have better performance characteristics.

```
lexicographicProduct2[G_?UndirectedGraphQ, H_?UndirectedGraphQ, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := AdjacencyGraph[
  Tuples[{VertexList[G], VertexList[H]}],
  With[{
    nG = VertexCount[G],
    nH = VertexCount[H]
    },
   Plus[
    KroneckerProduct[AdjacencyMatrix[G], ConstantArray[1, {nH, nH}]],
    KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[nG, SparseArray], AdjacencyMatrix[H]]
    ]
   ],
  opts
  ]
```

Here is a short timing comparison:

```
G = CycleGraph[20];
H = CycleGraph[30];
K1 = lexicographicProduct[G, H]; // RepeatedTiming // First
K2 = lexicographicProduct2[G, H]; // RepeatedTiming // First
K1 == K2
```

> 1.40
>
> 0.0543
>
> True

**Edit**

The product graphs have the tendency to be rather dense, so `AdjacencyGraph` might not be the best choice to construct it from the adjacency matrix: Doing so leads to a graph with `` GraphComputation`GraphRepresentation `` returning `"Simple"` which is in fact a sparse representation. The following leads to a result whose  `` GraphComputation`GraphRepresentation `` equals `"Incidence"`. This is also almost 10 times faster than `lexicographicProduct2` and even faster than Mathe172's fix for `` GraphComputation`GraphProduct `` (at least on my machine).

```
lexicographicProduct3[G_?UndirectedGraphQ, H_?UndirectedGraphQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Graph[
  Tuples[{VertexList[G], VertexList[H]}], 
  With[{nG = VertexCount[G], nH = VertexCount[H]},
    UpperTriangularize[Plus[
      KroneckerProduct[AdjacencyMatrix[G], ConstantArray[1, {nH, nH}]], 
      KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[nG, SparseArray], AdjacencyMatrix[H]]
      ]
     ]]["NonzeroPositions"],
  opts
  ]

K3 = lexicographicProduct3[G, H]; // RepeatedTiming // First
VertexList[K2] == VertexList[K3]
EdgeList[K2] == EdgeList[K3]
```

> 0.0059
>
> True
>
> True

Answer (score 8):

I did not know what [lexicographic product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_product_of_graphs) was, so I looked it up.

If performance is not critical, you can implement the definition quite directly.

```
lexicographicProduct[g1_?UndirectedGraphQ, g2_?UndirectedGraphQ, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 RelationGraph[
   (* two nodes are connected if their corresponding nodes in the first graph are connected *)
   EdgeQ[g1, First[#1] \[UndirectedEdge] First[#2]] || 
   (* or their corresponding nodes in the first graph are the same and their corresponding nodes in the second graph are connected *)
   (First[#1] === First[#2] && EdgeQ[g2, Last[#1] \[UndirectedEdge] Last[#2]]) &,

   (* the vertices are the cartesian product of the two vertex sets *)
   Tuples[{VertexList[g1], VertexList[g2]}],

   (* also allow setting graph options *)
   opt
 ]

lexicographicProduct[CycleGraph[5], CycleGraph[3]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

So I got `` GraphComputation`GraphProduct `` to work, and it appears to be even faster:

```
Unprotect[GraphComputation`GraphProduct];
DownValues[GraphComputation`GraphProduct] = 
  DownValues[GraphComputation`GraphProduct] /. "Lexicographic" -> "Lexicographical";
Protect[GraphComputation`GraphProduct];


K1 = lexicographicProduct[G, H, VertexLabels -> "Name"]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
K2 = lexicographicProduct2[G, H, VertexLabels -> "Name"]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
K3 = GraphComputation`GraphProduct[G, H, "Lexicographical"]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
IsomorphicGraphQ[K1, K2] && IsomorphicGraphQ[K2, K3]
(* 1.09 *)
(* 0.041 *)
(* 0.0086 *)
(* True *)
```

The issue is that there appears to be a typo in the definition of the function: The top-level `GraphProduct` function expects `"Lexicographic"`, while the inner function expects `"Lexicographical"`, leading to the unexpected error.

*Note*: Obviously, the function is undocumented, so be careful. Especially given that it's not even possible to call the function without fixing it up first.

Comment: I guess this is exactly what OP was after. Let's hope this functionality becomes public API in M12.0.  Some improvements were promised for 12.0.

Comment: Despite being undocumented, it might be worth reporting ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Good point - I've reported it now, let's see what they say